# How to create multiple files based on multiple records using php suppose i have 100 record create 1 file for every 10 record

Tags: php

This code is not working i want to print file for every 10 record.

```
if($con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","fileDemo")){
    //echo "DB CONEECTED";
    $sql = "select id from news order by id desc";
    $data_query=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($data_query)){
        $id=$data['id'];
        if(!file_exists("demo_file"."-".trim($id).".txt")){
            $file_c=fopen("demo_file"."-".trim($id).".txt", 'a'); 
            fwrite($file_c,$id);
            fclose($file_c);
        } 
        // $stringData.="Name: ".$data['name']." Age:".$data['age']."\n";
    }
}else{
    echo "CONNECTION FAILD";
}
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear your want to add first ten record in your file

Comment: yes, create a unique file for each 10 records. (Is that clear ??)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//open first file
$handle = fopen('filename.txt', 'w');
foreach ($records as $i => $record) {
   //if record is 10th then close prev file and open new
   if ($i % 10 == 0) {
       fclose($handle);
       $handle = fopen("filename_$i.txt", 'w');
   }
   //your logic here. Write to file I suppose
   fwrite($handle, $record);
}
//close file
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: it is working thanks.